# What are the parameters of the 0xC00000FD (Stack Overflow) error?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, runtime-error, stack-overflow

I've created a function which allocates an array, which is too big, on the stack (C++). The run results with this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000000013F4DEBF7 in xxx.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000043000).
```

I've never seen the "parameters" section assigned to a particular instance of a stack overflow error, and my search on the internet yielded no results. Does anyone know what these parameters mean? I've observed that for multiple runs of the same code, the first parameter stays constant and the second parameter changes, but stays in the 6-5 digit range. I'm very curious as to what they mean.

In case it matters, here's a MRE:

```
constexpr uint8_t LOG_2_OF_BUCKET_COUNT = 20;

int main(){
    uint32_t histogram[1 << LOG_2_OF_BUCKET_COUNT];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Nate: It's an OS "structured exception", the structured exception details won't depend on toolchain (build or runtime).  Just the OS.

Comment: Your array is about 4MB, that might be too large for the stack. Try `std::vector<uint32_t> histogram(1 << LOG_2_OF_BUCKET_COUNT);`

Comment: @churill Don't worry, the question is not about how I should fix my code. Just the parameters, I'll handle the rest. Thank you for the effort though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "parameters" are described in [the documentation for the `EXCEPTION_RECORD` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-exception_record).  Everything in that exception message came from `EXCEPTION_RECORD`, first `ExceptionAddress`, then a module name derived from `ExceptionAddress`, then `ExceptionCode` and its friendly name, and finally `NumberParameters` are read from `ExceptionInformation[]`.

Unfortunately for your purposes, the official documentation only describes parameters for `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` and `EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR` and says for all other exception types the parameters array has undefined contents.

With that caveat noted, there is consistency between the parameters for the two exception types where they are documented, and stack overflow is internally detected via an access violation, so it makes sense to decode as described for `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.  Specifically:

- The first element of the array contains a read-write flag that indicates the type of operation that caused the access violation.

  - If this value is zero, the thread attempted to read the inaccessible data.
  - If this value is 1, the thread attempted to write to an inaccessible address.
  - If this value is 8, the thread causes a user-mode data execution prevention (DEP) violation.
- The second array element specifies the virtual address of the inaccessible data.

Comparing to your captured exception information, the first element being a flag for (illegal read / illegal write / NX violation) is entirely believable.  The second element does not look much like a virtual address, however.  Perhaps for `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW` it gets reported relative to the thread stack base address.

Comment: "*stack overflow is internally detected via an access violation*" - huh? Where are you getting that from?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Quick overview of how stack growth works: There's a guard page on the end of the stack with no read, no write, no execute access.  When that's touched, the CPU generates an access violation fault, and the OS fault handler either commits more pages into the reserved stack address space and sets up a new guard page, or when the full reserved space is committed, raises a stack overflow exception.  (The OS handler for the access violation fault can also cause paging, manage copy-on-write, or raise access violation exception for AV faults not on a stack guard page)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: This guard page mechanism is why most people writing user-mode handlers for `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` catch the first occurrence just fine but typically see their program immediately crash if a second stack overflow occurs on the same thread -- because the compiler provided all the stack unwinding logic, but no one re-created the guard page after unwinding.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm aware of how stack growth works. It is not handled using `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, it uses `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION` instead. Two different things.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I didn't say it was `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` I said it was the same access violation CPU trap/fault.  That one also produces `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` under other conditions.  It's coming from the same kernel-provided fault handler, so it's reasonable to think that the fault handler might set the parameters the same way for both exceptions.  Of course we're into territory where the official name of the CPU trap/fault might vary between the different architectures supported by Windows (ix86, amd64, Itanium, Alpha, ARM)